# Log error in php

Tags: php, if-statement, logfile

I have some code that looks like this:

```
$log->error( 'addToWatch=['.$addToWatchPage.'] success=['.$success.']' );           
if( ( $success == 1 ) and ( $addToWatchPage == true ) ) {
   $log->error( 'adding to watch page' );           
} else {
   $log->error( 'NOT added to watch page' );        
}
```

When I run it, I am always going into the if statement and never into the else statement even if `$addToWatchPage` is false. See my log output below:

```
Sat Jan 26, 2013 @ 6:02 addToWatch=[false] success=[1] 
Sat Jan 26, 2013 @ 6:02 adding to watch page.
```

Can anyone explain why this is broken?

Comment: Is `$addToWatchPage` set to the string "false" or an actual false value? `var_dump($addToWatchPage)`

Comment: code you provided doesn't reproduce error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `$addToWatchPage` is a string containing `false`, otherwise your resultant first log message would be:

```
Sat Jan 26, 2013 @ 6:02 addToWatch=[] success=[1]
```

This would result in `$addToWatchPage == true` being evaluated as `true`, since `'false' == true` is a truthy expression (actually, any non-empty string other than `'0'` is true when casted to boolean).

Make sure `$addToWatchPage` is a boolean value instead of a string.

```
$addToWatchPage = false; // correct
$addToWatchPage = 'false'; // wrong
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to supply an identical operator '===' for the $addToWatchPage statement. Your current code with '==' is basically asking if $assToWatchPage contains anything. I would also remove the extra brackets but I'm not 100% sure if that makes a difference? I would also use && instead of and although someone might want to explain about operator Precedence.

Here:

```
    $log->error( 'addToWatch=['.$addToWatchPage.'] success=['.$success.']' );           
if( $success == 1  &&  $addToWatchPage === true ) {
   $log->error( 'adding to watch page' );           
} else {
   $log->error( 'NOT added to watch page' );        
}
```

See [This blog post on Triple Equals](http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/php-and-triple-equals/)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's a string problem:

```
if('false' == true)echo 'wtf';
```

Try casting:

```
$log->error("addToWatch=[$addToWatchPage] success=[$success]");           
if((int)$success === 1 && (string)$addToWatchPage === 'true') {
  $log->error('adding to watch page');           
}
else{
  $log->error('NOT added to watch page');        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use === instead of == width the $addToWatch